# Item key in HTTP POST request. How did my browser get it?

Tags: http, httprequest

I am trying to simulate an API for a website my company uses using python. I send GET and POST requests and listen for the response, parse it, etc. I've encountered a problem with trying to upload a file to the system. When I upload the file using the website normally my browser (Chrome) sends a POST request with a request body that looks like the following:

```
...
------WebKitFormBoundaryjSmcGTEU3c2TVyDq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_to_upload_0"; filename="2228789-2-Quote.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------WebKitFormBoundaryjSmcGTEU3c2TVyDq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_category_id"

5146
------WebKitFormBoundaryjSmcGTEU3c2TVyDq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_file_identifier"

2228789
------WebKitFormBoundaryjSmcGTEU3c2TVyDq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_id"

1748711477
------WebKitFormBoundaryjSmcGTEU3c2TVyDq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ticket_number"

CkuvRtqReP6Sy62gamx206ixksC4BE2z
...
```

This is the first HTTP request my browser sends after I click the upload button. My question is: how does my browser get the "file_id" and "ticket_number"? I looked at the page source of the page with the form, and neither of these numbers are anywhere on the page. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide source code of HTML form you're testing

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the answer is in the Javascript. The Javascript file was generating the file_id and whatnot.